# SwiftUI: Infinite Scrolling Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I need to create an infinite horizontal scrolling with `ScrollView` to scroll a panorama image. So I would like to make this scrolling infinite from both sides, is there any possible way to make it? I have searched maybe using `ScrollViewReader` can achieve this but no luck.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    Image("panorama")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 360º panorama image? Please attach a demo of image.

Comment: SceneKit might be better for this than SwiftUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually for such prepared image it is enough to load it only once, and we need only to Image presenters for it (note: they do not copy memory, but use the same loaded image). Everything else is just about layout on the fly moving current of-screen item depending on drag direction to left or to the right of current one.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part of code:

```
struct PanoramaView: View {
    let image: UIImage

    private struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable {
        let id = UUID()
        var pos: CGFloat!
    }

    @State private var items = [Item(), Item()]

    // ...

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            let centerY = gp.size.height / 2
            ForEach($items) { $item in
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .position(x: item.pos ?? 0, y: centerY)
                    .offset(x: dragOffset)
            }
        }
        .background(GeometryReader {
            Color.clear.preference(key: ViewSizeKey.self,
                                   value: $0.frame(in: .local).size)
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizeKey.self) {
            setupLayout($0)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .gesture(scrollGesture)
    }
```

and usage

```
    let panorama = UIImage(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "panorama", ofType: "jpeg")!)!
    var body: some View {
        PanoramaView(image: panorama)
            .frame(height: 300)   // to demo of dynamic internal layout
    }
```

[Complete test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestPanoramaImageView.swift)

Comment: It is a custom preference key, the declaration is present in referenced project.

Comment: It's works great! Just one thing is there any possible way make gesture scrolls smoothly like scrollview instead of stop after dragging?

Comment: Actually it is all about animation parameters. We do not know internal ScrollView settings, but you can configure to your own needs manipulating with animation duration and after-drag remaining distance to ease out.

Answer (score 0):

You can put 3 identical panorama images next to each other (to be able to scroll over the edges) and add a custom DragGesture, that basically jumps back to the relative position of the middle image.

This image is a bad example, obviously it will work better with a real 360° image ;)

**EDIT**:
now with predicted end location + animation and 5 images.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var dragOffset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero

    let imageWidth: CGFloat = 500
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                Image("image")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: imageWidth)
            }
        }
        .offset(x: offset + dragOffset)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({ value in
                    dragOffset = value.translation.width
                })
                .onEnded({ value in
                    withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                        dragOffset = value.predictedEndTranslation.width
                    }
                    offset = (offset + dragOffset).remainder(dividingBy: imageWidth)
                    dragOffset = 0
                })
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What about it reaches the end of the third image?  by the way I need scroll view behavior

Comment: it will never reach any end, because it always jumps back to the middle image. And what do you mean by "scrollview behaviour"?

Comment: Thank you I will test it, I mean smooth scrolling

Comment: ah ... scroll to predicted end location with animation ... that can also be done with DragGesture, but might get a little trickier. You might then use 5 images overall, and wait for the animation to stop before jumping back to the middle.

Comment: See edited code – seems it is NOT necessary to wait for animation to end.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it drastically decreases performance and increases memory usage. I think I need to link it with UIKit view